# Issue when importing Job Check box value from CSV file to Jira

Tags: csv, jira

I am now importing data from CSV file to Jira to update issues. All information regards to the issues are imported correctly. but When I try to import check box value( using custom Job check box). This information has not loaded. Any information will be appreciable?

Comment: Can you please post your csv file. What type of a custom field do you use for checkbox? Is it group checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try opening a support ticket at http://support.atlassian.com

Also, you can find the latest CSV documentation here: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Importing+Data+From+CSV